# How many bytes is a Hollerith card?

Tags: storage

I was showing my students a [Hollerith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_Hollerith) card this morning to show them some programmer's artifacts, along with an 8 inch floppy, a 5 1/4 inch floppy, a 3/12 inch floppy, an old reel-to-reel tape, etc.

Q: How many bytes could a Hollerith card hold?

Comment: Lets go with a traditional punch card, which is /slightly/ different from the old cards Hollerith himself may have used.

Standard punchcards were 80 characters, so 80 bytes.  If you want, you might even point out that systems that used those cards didn't have to an an 8-bit byte.  Some had 7 and others had 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hollerith cards have 80 columns, each holding a single ASCII or EBCDIC character.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card#IBM_80-column_punched_card_formats_and_character_codes

Comment: ASCII? I'll bet there were more punchcard systems using EBCDIC than ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Holerinth cards can hold an 80x12 matrix of holes, for a total of 960 bits, but cards which have too many holes punched out (sometimes called "lace cards") can be very fragile.  For that reason, among others, I believe that the character encodings used with punched cards are designed to mostly avoid having three or more consecutive holes punched in a column, at least with characters that would likely be repeated in consecutive columns.  If one wished to encode things to disallow two or more consecutive columns from having holes, each column could select one of 377 characters.  If one wished to allow two consecutive holes but disallow three, each column could select one of 1705 characters.